# Setting two mouse hooks in two threads

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, hook

I use the following code to set mouse local hook:

```
//declare hook handle global variable:
static HHOOK hhk;
//set new hook:
hhk = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE, (HOOKPROC)MouseWndProc, GetModuleHandle(NULL), GetCurrentThreadId());
```

and here is code of mouseproc callback function:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MouseWndProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT *pMouseStruct = (MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;

    if(nCode < 0)
    {
    return CallNextHookEx(hhk, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    //do something...

return CallNextHookEx(hhk, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Using described above code I set the local hook in the first thread.
In the second thread I also need to set new local hook. And problem is - when I set new hook (for second thread), the global variable `hhk` will be overwritten. And mouseproc of first hook now uses wrong hook handle. Right?
So what do I have to pass as first parameter of CallNextHookEx() function?

Comment: So use two variables.

Comment: And how, in this case, the mouseproc function determine its variable??

Comment: Why are you casting `MouseWndProc` to `HOOKPROC` when calling `SetWindowsHookEx`?

Comment: Declare two hook procedures `MouseWndProc1` and `MouseWndProc2`. One of them calls `MouseWndProcCommon(hhk1, nCode, wParam, lParam)` and the other calls `MouseWndProcCommon(hhk2, nCode, wParam, lParam)`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to know the `HHOOK` value inside the hook proc since [`CallNextHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644974(v=vs.85).aspx) ignores the first parameter (so you can just pass `NULL` for the first argument).

You need to save the two handles separately so you can remove the two hooks with [`UnhookWindowsHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644993(v=vs.85).aspx) later on.